# How do I update particular record in below scenario?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table data structure like below,

| ID | NAME | START_DATE | END_DATE | CREATE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Apple | 01-NOV-23 | 31-DEC-99 | 01-NOV-23 |
| 100 | Anar | 10-OCT-23 | 31-DEC-99 | 12-SEP-23 |
| 100 | Anar | 04-SEP-23 | 10-OCT-23 | 04-SEP-23 |
| 101 | Ant | 01-OCT-23 | 31-DEC-99 | 01-OCT-23 |
| 101 | Bee | 10-APR-23 | 31-DEC-99 | 12-APR-23 |
| 101 | Bee | 04-MAR-23 | 10-APR-23 | 04-MAR-23 |

I want to update data like below, (2nd row start_date should update like CREATE_DATE and END_DATE should update from next start_date)

| ID | NAME | START_DATE | END_DATE | CREATE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Apple | 01-NOV-2023 | 31-DEC-99 | 01-NOV-2023 |
| **100 | Anar | 12-SEP-2023 | 01-NOV-2023 | 12-SEP-2023** |
| 100 | Anar | 04-SEP-2023 | 10-OCT-23 | 04-SEP-2023 |
| 101 | Ant | 01-OCT-2023 | 31-DEC-99 | 01-OCT-2023 |
| **101 | Bee | 12-APR-2023 | 01-OCT-2023 | 12-APR-2023** |
| 101 | Bee | 04-MAR-2023 | 10-APR-23 | 10-APR-23 |

Note- The thing her is for one id one user should have end_date as 31-DEC-99

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (so we can just copy-paste and execute them); and a complete English explanation of the logic including why are the second and fifth rows updating but not the third or sixth and what your final note means.

Comment: Why in the expected output has the final row changed its `create_date`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you:

- want to modify the rows only when `end_date` is `9999-12-31`;
- want to display the `create_date` as the `start_date`; and
- want to take the next `create_date` as the `end_date` if it exists else use the current `end_date`.

Given that assumption then you can use `CASE` expressions and the `LEAD` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT id,
       name,
       CASE
       WHEN end_date = DATE '9999-12-31'
       THEN create_date
       ELSE start_date
       END AS start_date,
       CASE
       WHEN end_date = DATE '9999-12-31'
       THEN LEAD(create_date, 1, end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY create_date)
       ELSE end_date
       END AS end_date,
       create_date
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY id, create_date
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, CREATE_DATE) AS
SELECT 100, 'Apple', DATE '2023-11-01', DATE '9999-12-31', DATE '2023-11-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'Anar',  DATE '2023-10-10', DATE '9999-12-31', DATE '2023-09-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'Anar',  DATE '2023-09-04', DATE '2023-10-10', DATE '2023-09-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'Ant',   DATE '2023-10-01', DATE '9999-12-31', DATE '2023-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'Bee',   DATE '2023-04-10', DATE '9999-12-31', DATE '2023-04-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101, 'Bee',   DATE '2023-03-04', DATE '2023-04-10', DATE '2023-03-04' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME | START_DATE | END_DATE | CREATE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Anar | 2023-09-04 00:00:00 | 2023-10-10 00:00:00 | 2023-09-04 00:00:00 |
| 100 | Anar | 2023-09-12 00:00:00 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00 | 2023-09-12 00:00:00 |
| 100 | Apple | 2023-11-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00 |
| 101 | Bee | 2023-03-04 00:00:00 | 2023-04-10 00:00:00 | 2023-03-04 00:00:00 |
| 101 | Bee | 2023-04-12 00:00:00 | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 2023-04-12 00:00:00 |
| 101 | Ant | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 | 2023-10-01 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eUIOWbbL)

Comment: @Nimantha The initial line is not commentary, it states that the question is not entirely clear but that certain behaviour can be inferred from the data and that the OP (and anyone else who finds the answer valuable) should insure that they review the assumptions used in the answer and check that those assumptions hold for the logic that they are trying to implement. If the question clearly defined the logic then that caveat would not be required.

Comment: Note that if additional details are required, a comment could be posted under the question asking for clarification. Should the entire first paragraph be removed (instead of integrating both)? Revision 2 or Revision 4?

Comment: @Nimantha If you look under the question you will see that I have left such comments. This answer is a "best guess" as to the requirements given the available data and the first line is a valuable reminder to all readers they need to validate the assumptions (i.e. it does not need removing until/unless the OP clarifies the question).